# How do I prevent a user which already exists in the database from from being added again?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a registration form in PHP for my application. However, I do not want users to register with the same username or email address.

Therefore, I have the following code to check if there is a record in the "users" table that matches either the username or email that is entered into the registration form.

```
// Check if user exists
    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= ? OR email= ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $user_check_query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
        while ($user = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            if ($user['username'] === $username) {
                array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
            }

            if ($user['email'] === $email) {
                array_push($errors, "Email already exists");
            }
        }
    }
```

As seen in the code above, if the user is already existing in the database it is pushed to the errors array.

Then before an INSERT INTO statement is sent to the database, an if statement is checked to see if the count of the errors array is equal to 0. If the errors array is not equal to 0 then INSERT INTO statement should not be sent to the database.

```
    // Register the user if there are no errors
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Securely hash the password

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, name, password, email, dob, gender) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $username, $name, $hashed_password, $email, $dob, $gender);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: ../profile.html');
    }
}
```

However, the above code sends the INSERT INTO statement regardless of whether a matching user is found in the table or not.

Comment: Have you verified that your fist section of code actually creates the correct entries in the `$errors` array? Did you [check for PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/3986005)?

Comment: Why do you repost your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78203186/how-do-i-prevent-a-user-which-already-exists-in-the-database-from-from-being-add?